# Laravel Key Value Pair in Get Request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, request, axios

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Axios to make async requests to my backend and retrieve data based on the get request parameters of my api endpoint.

I can see in inspector I'm making the following request to the server:

```
https://website.com/api/users?page=1&sort=%7B%22fieldName%22:%22lname%22,%22order%22:%22asc%22%7D&filter=
```

Which decodes to:

```
https://website.com/api/users?page=1&sort={"fieldName":"lname","order":"asc"}&filter=
```

Looks like I can successfully get pieces of the query via:

```
return $request->query('sort');
```

which returns:

```
data:
    fieldName: "lname"
    order: "asc"
```

But when I use:

```
return $request->query('sort.fieldName');
```

I don't get anything. Should I not be using the [dot notation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input)? How do I get each key / value pair of the sort input? Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you please go to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Check what error message it is showing at the bottom of the page. I am not expert so I can't help you much. But I am saying because most of the time I debug using this file .

Comment: I'm actually just returning the value and then logging it in the console on the frontend. I'm not getting any errors from `return $request->query('sort.fieldName');` just blank data returned. Good thought though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you could use dot notation, but at any rate you could try just converting it from `json` to an associative array.

```
$sort = json_decode($request->query('sort'), true);
```

This should then allow you to do something like, `$sort[‘fieldName’]`. The `true` parameter tells the decode to turn it into an associative array versus being returned an object.

Comment: You can’t use the dot notation because laravel is expecting a string, it doesn’t know `sort` is `json`, so the above will allow you to manually do it.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Bird. This was exactly what I needed. Didn't know about the assoc param of json_decode nor about Laravel expecting a string. Makes sense!

Comment: No problem glad I could help!